# How do I set up my Flashpoint/Godox triggers to use an AD200 with my OEM hotshoe flash?

Tags: canon, off-camera-flash, godox

Can anyone please tell me the steps for setting up Flashpoint R2 E-TTL 2.4G Wireless Flash Trigger Receiver For Canon (Godox X1R-C) triggers with a Canon Speedlite 430EX, AD200, and a Canon 80D? I would like to know how to use both the flashes together at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

You also need a **transmitter** unit on the hotshoe of your camera to send the hotshoe signals to your slave/receiver units. If you want TTL and HSS triggering, you can use any of the following Godox transmitters (Adorama names in parentheses):

- X1T (Flashpoint R2 transmitter)
- XPro (Flashpoint R2 Pro transmitter)
- Flashpoint R2 Pro II (no Godox version)
- X2T (Flashpoint R2 II transmitter)
- Any Godox TTL speedlight:

  - TT350 (Flashpoint Zoom Mini TTL R2)
  - V350 (Flashpoint Zoom Li-on Mini TTL R2)
  - TT685 (Flashpoint Zoom R2 Thinklite TTL)
  - V860II (Flashpoint Zoom Li-on R2 TTL)
  - V1 (Flashpoint Zoom Li-on X R2 TTL)

There are other transmitter units in the system, but the TT600 and V850II speedlights aren't TTL/HSS radio masters, the XT32 doesn't do TTL, and the XT16 doesn't do either TTL or HSS.

Obviously, you also need to get a version of your transmitter unit that matches your system:

- -C : Canon
- -N : Nikon
- -S : Sony
- -O : Olympus/Panasonic
- -F : Fuji
- -P : Pentax

Steps:

1. Make sure all your batteries are good and fully charged.
2. Put the transmitter on your camera hotshoe.

   1. Make sure the camera is set up to treat the transmitter like an on-camera flash. Take it *out* of any "wireless" flash modes. These are typically for proprietary "smart" optical triggering. With Canon turn wireless "off"; for Sony, set the flash to "fill" not "wireless".
   2. Make sure the transmitter is seated completely forward on the hotshoe.
3. Put the X1R receiver on your OEM speedlight's foot. Make sure the flash is properly seated.
4. Turn everything on (the AD200 has a built-in receiver, so doesn't need one added).
5. Set everything to use the same channel.
6. Assign groups to each of the lights. For example, if you want to use the AD200 with separate settings from the speedlight, you can assign the AD200 to Group A, and the speedlight to Group B.
7. Use the transmitter to make any settings changes on the lights. (If you are in a system other than Canon, you may need to put the OEM speedlight into TTL mode to get M power control. You may not see the power settings change on the flash's LCD, but you should see it in the images themselves).
8. Shoot.

Godox and Adorama do keep all the documentation as downloadable PDFs on their websites. With Godox, all the firmware update software and files are listed, with all the manual PDFs afterwards on [their downloads page](http://www.godox.com/EN/Download.html). Adorama puts the PDF download links on a 'User Manual' button on the flash's listing page.